# Sympy unable to evaluate integral of log(sin(x)) from 0 to π/2. what to do?

Tags: python, sympy

I have tried this but it is showing unevaluated answer

```
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
x=sym.symbols('x')
z=sym.log(sym.sin(x))
z.integrate((x,0,sym.pi/2))
```

it is showing ans as

```
π
2
∫log(sin(x))dx
0
```

what should i do to get the correct ans as `-π/2log(2)`

Comment: `log(sin(0))` is undefined, is it really possible to get an integral when it's part of the range?

Comment: As @MarkRansom, what you're really trying to calculate is `sym.limit(z.integrate((x, y, sym.pi/2)), y, 0, '+')`.  But sympy is failing on that, too.

Comment: yes I tried sym.limit(z.integrate((x, y, sym.pi/2)), y, 0, '+') but it is showing error. but the definite integral exist and it is -π/2log(2)